# c++ strings and file input

Tags: c++, input

Ok, its been a while since I've done any file input or string manipulation but what I'm attempting to do is as follows

```cpp
while(infile >> word) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        if(word[i] == '\n') { 
            cout << "Found a new line" << endl; 
            lineNumber++; 
        }

        if(!isalpha(word[i])) {
            word.erase(i);
        }

        if(islower(word[i])) {
            word[i] = toupper(word[i]);         
        }
    }
}
```

Now I assume this is not working because >> skips the new line character?? If so, whats a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [getline](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) function for [istream](https://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/).

Answer (score 9):

I'll guess that `word` is a `std::string`. When using `>>`, the first white-space character terminates the 'word' and the next invocation will skip white-space so no white-space while occur in `word`.

You don't say what you're actually trying to do but for line based input you should consider using the free function `std::getline` and then splitting each line into words as a separate step.

E.g.

```
std::string line;
while( std::getline( std::cin, line ) )
{
    // parse line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`getline()`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/getline)?

```
string line;
while(getline(infile, line))
{
    //Parse each line into individual words and do whatever you're going to do with them.
}
```